# cant get './MongoDB' with vue-cli and webpack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, webpack, vue.js, vue-material

i have some problem to add mongodb, my git is:

https://github.com/yoavshtainer/NodeWebpackTest

my error is:

> cannot find module './MongoDB'

i'm using `windows 10` with `vue-cli` and `webpack`.

my package:

```
"dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "^2.2.24",
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "vue-material": "^0.7.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.2.0",
    "vue-router": "^2.2.0"
  },
```

i check my **package.json** and `mongo` in it and try to change the path, but nothing works.

Comment: surely it should be `require('mongodb')`, why are you giving it a relative path to the `src` directory - there is no mongodb in the `src` directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module './MongoDB' is saying find the `MongoDB.js` in the `src` directory of your folder. But you haven't got one in there.

If you are referring to a module in the `packages.json` then you don't use relative paths, a.k.a `./`, just use the name

```
require('mongodb');
```

Comment: thank you! i found my problem with your answer, i forgot to add my MongoDB.js... so this was my problem...

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add my MongoDB.js, this was the problem.